# login with amazon on android traget sdk 34 not work

Tags: android-14, login-with-amazon

My app used the LWA SDK to log in to Amazon and it worked very well until I upgraded the target SDK of the Android project to 34. However, on an Android 14 phone with the Amazon shopping app installed, I was unable to redirect to the Amazon shopping app for SSO. When I uninstalled the Amazon shopping app, I was able to redirect to the browser to log in. When I lower the target SDK to 33, I can also perform SSO.

I am using the LWA SDK updated in September 2023, version 3.1.2.It seems that it is still not compatible with Android 14

Is there anyone who can help me solve this problem